# A subscriber (python script) problem? Please correct..... the error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write the python script to subscribe topic "cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" as keyboard Teleop node publishes message on this topic

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('test')
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import String
  
def callback(data):
     print rospy.get_name(),  "%f %f %f %f %f %f" %data.linx %data.liny %data.linz %data.angx %data.angy %data.angz

def listener():
      rospy.init_node('subs1', anonymous=True)
      rospy.Subscriber("cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop", Twist, callback)
      rospy.spin()
 
if __name__ == '__main__' :
      listener()
```

Error on terminal ............

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/admin-pc/mywork/test/scripts/subs1.py", line 4, in 
roslib.load_manifest('test')
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest 
sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
return self._load_manifest(name) 
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name) 
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths) 
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: test 
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros 
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share 
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks 
ROS path [3]=/home/admin-pc/mywork 
ROS path [4]=/home/admin-pc/ros_workspace$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72229/a-subscriber-(python-script)-problem?-please-correct.....-the-error/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error means that rospkg cannot find the package "test". Have you create it as a package, and is it location in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ? Does `rospack find test` finds the path ?

---

Originally posted by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) with karma: 336 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-08-12**:
I have to check by rospack find test again. However I have checked it earlier and it was working well. More over there 3-4 more scrips in the this test package and all are working well.
If there is some other possibility then please let me know.

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-12**:
Don't forget to source the setup.bash file for your catkin workspace in *every terminal* you are using.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-08-12**:
I am using rosbuild for it ..... is there any specific suggestion in that regard Please tell.